# Spring Kafka - "ErrorHandler threw an exception" and lost some records

Tags: spring-kafka

Having `Consumer` polling 2 records at a time, i.e.:

```java
    @Bean
    ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> config = Map.of(
                BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092",
                GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "my-consumers",
                AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest",
                MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 2);

        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config, new StringDeserializer(), new StringDeserializer());
    }
```

and `ErrorHandler` which can fail handling faulty record:

```java
class MyListenerErrorHandler implements ContainerAwareErrorHandler {

    @Override
    public void handle(Exception thrownException,
                       List<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>> records,
                       Consumer<?, ?> consumer,
                       MessageListenerContainer container) {
        simulateBugInErrorHandling(records.get(0));
        skipFailedRecord(); // seek offset+1, which never happens
    }

    private void simulateBugInErrorHandling(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record) {
        throw new NullPointerException(
                "DB transaction failed when saving info about failure on offset = " + record.offset());
    }
}
```

Then such scenario is possible:

1. Topic gets 3 records
2. `Consumer` polls 2 records at a time
3. `MessageListener` fails to process the first record due to faulty payload
4. `ErrorHandler` fails to process the failure and itself throws an exception, e.g. due to some temporary issue
5. Third record gets processed
6. Second record is never processed (never enters `MessageListener`)

**How to ensure no record is left unprocessed when `ErrorHandler` throws an exception with above scenario?**

*My goal is to achieve stateful retry logic with delays, but for brevity I omitted code responsible for tracking failed records and delaying retry.*

---

I'd expect that after `ErrorHandler` throws an exception, skipping an entire batch of records should not happen. But it does.

1. Is it correct behavior?
2. Should I rather deal with commits manually that use Spring/Kafka defaults?
3. Should I use different `ErrorHandler` or `handle` method? (I need an access to `Container` to make a `pause()` for delayed retry logic; cannot use `Thread.sleep()`)

Somehow related issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1265

Full code: https://github.com/ptomaszek/spring-kafka-error-handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The consumer has to be re-positioned (using seeks) in order to re-fetch the records after the failed one.

Use a `DefaultErrorHandler` (2.8.x and later) or a `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` with earlier versions.

You can add retry options and a recoverer to deal with the failed record; by default it is just logged.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#default-eh

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.7.x/reference/html/#seek-to-current

You need to do the seeks first (or in a finally block), before any exceptions can be thrown; the container does not commit the offset if the error handler throws an exception.

Kafka maintains 2 offsets - the current committed offset and the current position (set to the committed offset when the consumer starts). The next poll always returns the next record after the last poll. unless a seek is performed.

The default error handlers catch any exceptions thrown by the recoverer and makes sure that the current (and subsequent) records will be returned by the next poll. See `SeekUtils.doSeeks()`.

Comment: I need a custom `ErrorHandler`.
It can however throw an exception before repositioning with `seek`. Then it seems the offset of the latest record from `records` gets committed anyway with the next `poll`. In the end the failing record (and remaining from he first pack of `records`) are never reprocessed

Comment: You need to do the seeks first (or in a finally block), before any exceptions can be thrown; it does NOT commit the offset; Kafka maintains 2 offsets - the current committed offset and the current position (set to the committed offset when the consumer starts). The next poll always returns the next record after the last poll. unless a seek is performed. The default error handlers catch any exceptions thrown by the recoverer and makes sure that the current (and subsequent) records will be returned by the next poll. See `SeekUtils.doSeeks()`.